# Converting byte array of length 3 into an int

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a byte array of length 3, representing a <strike>decimal</strike> binary number. My question:

Why is this correct:

(a) `int x = (array[0] & 0xff) << 16 | (array[1] & 0xff) << 8 | (array[2] & 0xff);`

but this isn't?

(b) `int x = array[0] << 16 | array[1] << 8 | array[2];`

Let's say array[0] is `01010101`. Isn't this what happens?

`array[0] & 0xff = 01010101 & 11111111 = 01010101 = array[0]`

Why is option b) wrong?

Comment: Perhaps when `array[*]` is negative, and when it is promoted from `byte` to `int`, it produces unnecessary `1`s.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "representing a decimal number" as opposed to just "representing a number"? I don't see anything decimal in the way you are treating the array.

Comment: @Gassa They're not 'unnecessary'. They are required to be there by the semantics of negative numbers in twos-complement.

Comment: @EJP Right you are. I actually meant something like "offending" for the particular problem at hand, and chose the wrong word. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what happens when the most significant bit of `array[0]` is 1.

For example:

```
array[0] = (byte)0xff;
System.out.println (array[0] << 16);
System.out.println ((array[0] & 0xff) << 16);
```

output:

```
-65536
16711680
```

`array[0]` is converted to an `int` for the sake of the left-shift operator. If it has a negative value as a `byte`, it will have a negative value as an `int`, and will have a negative value after the left-shift.

When you perform bit-wise AND with `0xff`, you make sure the result will be positive.

Comment: Ah, I see. When doing a left shift, it will replicate the mos significant bit, so if array[0] is for example ``10101010``, ``array[0] << 8 = 1111111110101010``. However, I still don't understand how the ``&`` operator prevents this, since ``array[0] & 0xFF = array[0]``, so we'd apply the left shift to the exact same byte?

Comment: @Tirafesi `array[0]` is upcasted to an `int` before the bit-wise AND is performed, so `10101010` becomes `11111111111111111111111110101010` and after the bit-wise AND you get `00000000000000000000000010101010`. So you shift-left `00000000000000000000000010101010` instead of shifting left `11111111111111111111111110101010`.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. Thank you :)

Comment: I've sometimes wondered why Java doesn't have a `<<<` operator as the opposite of `>>>`. This kind-of explains it.